# Как узнать является ли строка анаграммой палиндрома за O(n) и без дополнительной памяти?

Tags: javascript, алгоритм

На входе даётся рандомная строка без спец символов и пробелов. Нужно вывести 1, если строка - перестановка палиндрома и 0, если нет.
В этой [статье](https://medium.com/@vitkarpov/cracking-the-coding-interview-1-4-33c6c0b203c8) описывается метод с использованием битового вектора, но, так как с этим я не знаком, возможно ли решить данную задачу по-другому?
Я пытался сделать так, но не укладываюсь в ограничения:

```
function solution(s) {
  const obj = {};
  s.split("").forEach(elem => {
    if(obj[elem]) {
      obj[elem]--;
    } else {
      obj[elem]===0 ? obj[elem]++ : obj[elem] = 1;
    }
  })
  return (Object.values(obj).reduce((a,b) => a+b) > 1) ? 0 : 1;
}
```

Comment: @pavel, такого вектора не будет, в случае палиндрома.

Comment: _не укладываюсь в ограничения_ - о каких ограничениях речь?

Comment: В общем-то у вас довольно итересный вариант решения, но он несколько нелогичен. По идее вам нужно для каждого символа использовать ваирант - если его нет в **obj** - то его добавлять. Если есть, то удалять. Потом по факту проверить что в **obj** есть больше одного элемента, то вернуть 0 иначе 1.

Comment: @newman, именно это и происходит в коде

Comment: @Grundy, я же занимаю дополнительную память создавая  объект и массив при возврате, разве нет?

Comment: @Overground, да и это первый вариант из статьи по ссылке. Ты просто считаешь количество букв и потом его проверяешь. Второй вариант - делает то же самое, просто для хранения подсчета использует целое число

Comment: В целом странное условие, учитывая что рассматривается только 26 букв, любое (не слишком кривое) решение будет O(1) от длины строки

Comment: @AlexeyTen, с натяжкой можно сказать только, что добавление элемента в сет/массив немного более затратно по памяти чем выставление бита в числе, но все упирается в размер алфавита в итоге

Comment: @Grundy оно там не очень явно как-то происходит.

Comment: @Overground судя по всему когда пишут про дополнительную память, то имеют в виду строк. А вообще без дополнительной памяти и за O(n) тут вариантов особо и нет.

Comment: @newman, без дополнительной памяти даже цикл нельзя сделать, вероятно речь шла про константную память `O(1)`

Answer (score 1):

Про битовый вектор. Как это понимаю я. Предположим что в строке могут быть только буквы латинского алфавита в нижнем регистре. Т.е. таких букв может быть 26. Т.е. для хранения информации будет достаточно 32 битного числа. Первый бит будет хранить информацию о букве *a*, второй о *b*, третий - *c* и т.д.
Устанавливать или сбрасывать биты можно с помощью битовых операций. Если назначить буквам числа (так сказать индексы).
*a* = 1
*b* = 2
*c* = 4
*d* = 8
и т.д. до *z* как степени двойки.

Дальше предположим, есть переменная **vector** = 0;
Т.е. все биты сброшены. Е
Начинаем проход по строке. Встретилась буква *b* - нужно установить второй бит. В данной случае можно и нужно использовать операцию **XOR**.
`vector = vector XOR 2`

Почему **XOR**? - потому что с ее помощью можно решить задачу подсчета четного числа букв.

Т.е. когда в следующий раз попадется буква *b* - то сделав еще раз **XOR** для **vector** и **2** - мы сбросим второй бит в ноль. Тем самым не нужна дополнительная проверка в каком он находится состоянии. **XOR** все  "сделает" за нас.

А дальше надо будет проверить получился ли **vector** равный 0. Или же там установлен всего лиш один бит. Проверить на то что есть один бит - можно сравненим числа vector с теми числами, которые мы приписывали для букв (степень двойки).

Как вариант, решение может быть таким. Здесь **obj** это по сути битовый вектор, который упоминается в вопросе.
Если символ встречается первый раз, то свойство добавляется (в числе ставится бит в соответствующую поизицию). Если символ встречается второй раз, то свойство удаляется из объекта (в числе сбрасывается бит в соответствующей позиции).

После цикла проверяем что в объекте нет свойств или осталось только одно - в таком случае строка подходит под условия.

```js
function solution(s) {
  const obj = Object();
  s.split("").forEach(elem => {
    if(obj[elem]) {
      delete obj[elem];
    } else {
      obj[elem] = 1;
    }
  })
  return Object.keys(obj).length<=1?1:0;
}

console.log(solution("dfghgfd"));
console.log(solution("aaa"));
console.log(solution("abcdefg"));
```

Comment: код в вопросе делает то же самое что и в твоем примере. Разница только в реализации подсчета

Answer (score -1):

Вроде так

```
  // Создаем хэш-таблицу для хранения количества каждого символа в строке
  const charCount = {};
  let oddCharCount = 0;

  // Проходим по всем символам в строке и увеличиваем количество символов в хэш-таблице
  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    const char = str.charAt(i);

    if (charCount[char]) {
      charCount[char]++;
    } else {
      charCount[char] = 1;
    }
  }

  // Считаем количество символов с нечетным количеством вхождений
  for (const char in charCount) {
    if (charCount[char] % 2 === 1) {
      oddCharCount++;
    }
  }

  // Если количество символов с нечетным количеством вхождений больше 1, строка не является анаграммой палиндрома
  return oddCharCount <= 1;
}
```

Comment: Вроде бы да. Но слишком много лишнего.